# Laravel and barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (html not displaying correctly in Pdf )

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I need to create like this model in PDF :

[image: Label a4/8]

In html works great like this :
[image]

But when i loaded to pdf(barryvdh dompdf) I got this result? i'don't know why some  content changes his place

[image]

This my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
table{
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td{
  text-align: left;
  border:1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height:150px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    
  <tr>
        @foreach($colisenattent as $coli)  
        <td>
            {{$coli->data}}
        </td>
        @endforeach
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the structure data of $colisenattent

Comment: `code` public function Etiquette($id){
        $colisenattent = DB::table('blitems')
        ->join('colis', 'blitems.colis_id', '=', 'colis.id')
        ->join('bl','blitems.bl_id','=','bl.id')
        ->join('users','colis.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->where('bl_id','=',$id)->select('colis.*', 'blitems.*','users.telephone as nation','users.boutique as store')->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('Client.Pdf.Etiquettes',compact('colisenattent'));
        return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
    }

Comment: add this by editing the question hard to read here

Comment: by structure I mean what is shown in `dd($colisenattent );`

Comment: <code>Collection {#269 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => {#271 ▼
      +"id": 79
      +"code": "Kamron Lesch"
      +"etat": "Expidié"
      +"destinataire": "Sedrick Bogisich"
      +"telephone": "(987) 794-4519 x6352"
      +"prix": "286"
      +"produit": "Machine Café"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"created_at": "2020-12-13 14:43:50"
      +"updated_at": "2020-12-13 14:43:50"
      +"colis_id": 103
      +"bl_id": 24
      +"nation": "0666813581"
      +"store": "Lc shop"
    }</code>

Comment: No problem in data because i used only html content also didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225907/discussion-between-abdo-abo-and-bhucho).

Answer (score 2):

The issue lied in your css, At first glance though it looks ok.
At first `display: inline-block;` this css breaks the dompdf code so you will end up in some dompdf error,

> Dompdf\Exception
> The row #1 could not be found, please file an issue in the tracker with the HTML code

So you need to remove that.
use `vertical-align: top;` instead.
I have added my own styling as well to make it close to ideal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px 0px 1px 0px;
 
}

th, td{
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Text</td>
            <td>Text Text</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Text</td>
            <td>Text Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Text</td>
            <td>Text Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

DEMO Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is currently creating a single row with `n` columns. Do you instead want to create `n/2` rows with two columns?

If so, try something like this:

```html
<table>
    @for($i = 0; $i < count($colisenattent); $i += 2)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $colisenattent[$i]->data }}
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (isset($colisenattent[$i + 1]))
                    {{ $colisenattent[$i + 1]->data }}
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endfor
</table>
```

Comment: Works great in html but when i try to convert to pdf ,I got this error : The row #1 could not be found, please file an issue in the tracker with the HTML code

Comment: It looks like the `display: inline-block;` can be problematic? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51135354/6472849